# How can I make XCursor Themes "lefty"

Tags: linux, xorg

I have some XCursor themes I like. But since I'm a left hander I want to know if I can use some setting option in Xdefaults that make "Lefty" cursors the default.

Or do I have to get specific lefty themes, or do I have to hack those themes do some rename|symlink trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have installed the xcursor-themes package for your distro you can simply run:

```
$ xsetroot -cursor_name right_ptr
```

This will set the "lefty" hand black pointer as default. To make it permanent put the command somewhere in your startup scripts or startup applications settings. As for making lefty themes from normal themes I don't know. My guess is that there are already plenty of lefty themes out there for everyone to enjoy.